# javaFX color of wireframe is different on AMD and Nvidia

Tags: eclipse, javafx, nvidia, amd-gpu, wireframe

I have to visualize movementlines in JavaFX 8. I'm using Eclipse, newest Java update (8 update 72) and Windows 10 64bit. My home PC runs with a AMD HD 5870, my notebook and my PC at work have an graphics-card by Nvidia (GT760m and GTX 670). In my program, there is a triangle mesh and movementlines (triangle mesh with two coords the same, round about 300 coordinations).

Here is my problem: the triangle mesh has a color. The movmentline has the same color. On Nvidia PCs the movementline color is really the same as the color of the triangle mesh. AMD PC shows the movementline is black.

Here is the code for the triangle mesh:

```
    PhongMaterial material;
    MeshView meshView;
    TriangleMesh mesh;
    
    material = new PhongMaterial(color);

    float[] points = {  (float) pointN.getX(),  (float) pointN.getY(),  (float) pointN.getZ(), 
                        (float) pointEL.getX(), (float) pointEL.getY(), (float) pointEL.getZ(), 
                        (float) pointER.getX(), (float) pointER.getY(), (float) pointER.getZ() };

    int[] faces = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 };

    mesh = new TriangleMesh();
    mesh.getPoints().setAll(points);
    mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0, 0);
    mesh.getFaces().setAll(faces);

    meshView = new MeshView(mesh);
    meshView.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
    meshView.setMaterial(material);
    meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.BACK);
```

And this is for the movementline:

```
PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial(color); 
            float[] pointss = { points.get(i).x,  points.get(i).y,  -points.get(i).z, 
                                points.get(i).x,  points.get(i).y,  -points.get(i).z,
                                points.get(i+1).x,  points.get(i+1).y,  -points.get(i+1).z
                    };
    
            int[] faces = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 };
            
            TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
            mesh.getPoints().setAll(pointss);
            mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0, 0);
            mesh.getFaces().setAll(faces);
            
            MeshView meshView = new MeshView(mesh);
            meshView.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
            meshView.setMaterial(material);
            meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.BACK);
```

In my opinion it is the same construct of code. OS, Drivers, Java and Eclipse are up to date on all systems.

Has anybody an idea to solve this color Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the below to set the color of the wireframe of a TriangleMesh - (its Scala not Java)

```
      val mesh: TriangleMesh = new TriangleMesh

      mesh.getPoints.setAll(pointsCube: _*)
      mesh.getTexCoords.setAll(0, 0)
      mesh.getFaces.setAll(facesCube: _*)

      val blackMaterial: PhongMaterial = new PhongMaterial
      blackMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.BLACK)
      val meshView = new MeshView(mesh)
      meshView.drawModeProperty.setValue(DrawMode.LINE)
      meshView.setMaterial(blackMaterial)
```